# Transfer Item(s) from Hardcore to Standard

Tags: path-of-exile

In path of exile, it is possible to transfer items from a hardcore mode to a stardard (Non-hardcore) mode without the use of a character dying?

So far I only know of a method where you create a new a new hardcore mode character, make it hold all the items you want to transfer over, and purposely make it die.

Is there any other methods excluding the one I just mentioned?

Comment: No, as far as I know that's the only way of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

No.

As Seth already answered. The only was of cross-league transfer is, when a hardcore character dies.